# update column locality_name to market name but i have same locality_id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Locality-market with column as :

```
Locality_id
Locality_name
market_id
market_name
```

i am trying to update `locality-name` to `market_name` the query i am using is:

```
update table_1
set locality_name = market_name 
where locality_name = ''
```

But the problem is i am getting different `locality_name` for a similar `locality_id`

> [different locality_name for similar locality_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrGIJ.jpg)

I want to have one locality_name for one `locality_id`

```
1414,   Nord Ouest, 110,    Port-de-Paix
1415,   Ouest ,     109,    Port-au-Prince
1416,   Sud,        102,    Cayes
1417,   Sud Est,    105,    Jacmel
1425,   *blank* ,   2601,   San Pedro Sula
1426,   *blank*,    2608,   Tegucigalpa
1484,   *blank*,    4676,   Mayabunder
1484,   *blank*,    1392,   Port Blair
1485,   *blank*,    4666,   Jadcherla
1485,   *blank*,    4671,   Karimnagar
1485,   *blank*,    4692,   Suryapet
1485,   *blank*,    4695,   Tirupathi
1485,   *blank*,    4699,   Visakhapatnam
```

i want to update locality name in such a way that i always get only one `locality_name` for every `locality_id`

```
1414,   Nord Ouest,     110,    Port-de-Paix
1415,   Ouest,          109,    Port-au-Prince
1416,   Sud,            102,    Cayes
1417,   Sud Est,        105,    Jacmel

1425,   San Pedro Sula, 2601,   San Pedro Sula
1426,   Tegucigalpa,    2608,   Tegucigalpa
1484,   Mayabunder,     4676,   Mayabunder
1484,   Mayabunder,     1392,   Port Blair
1485,   Jadcherla,      4666,   Jadcherla
1485,   Jadcherla,      4671,   Karimnagar
1485,   Jadcherla,      4692,   Suryapet
1485,   Jadcherla,      4695,   Tirupathi
1485,   Jadcherla,      4699,   Visakhapatnam
```

Comment: Are you certain that there's not already a table with unique locality_id & Locality_name? Perhaps called "Locality"?  Keeping duplicate names goes against the practise of normalization.

Comment: I have but in some cases locality name is not there , therefore i have to rename the locality_name as market_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function like `FIRST_VALUE` in a CTE.
Then update the CTE to update the table.

```
;with cte as (
  select locality_id, locality_name, market_id, market_name
  , new_locality_name = first_value(market_name) 
                        over (partition by locality_id
                              order by market_name asc)
  from table_1
  where (locality_name is null or locality_name = '')
    and (market_name is not null) 
)
update cte
set locality_name = new_locality_name;
```